# VS Default Blank App is not Blank App. How to create a real Blank App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

It seems to me that the Default blank app from Visual Studio is not at all a blank app.

It comes with a ton of files including some xml files. When I think of a `Blank App` I imagine a solution without files at all. And then you can go and create your first class and so on. But in Visual Studio there it seems it doesn't behave like this. Is this just the way of the `C# Environment` in Visual Studio ? Or is there a way to create a real blank App?

I observe that even the Assets folder is filled with Images in the `Blank App`.

Comment: What kind of app are you trying to create?

Comment: what is Blank App? you should clarify what project type you are using (eg ASP.Net, WPF, Console, .Net Core...) Probably Console app is the most blankish of all

Comment: If you want a blank app with _"no files at all"_ then **don't use Visual Studio**.  1) From Windows Explorer navigate to a folder and click **New Folder**.   Job done

Comment: @MickyD Snark aside, I'm not sure if MSBuild can compile stuff without at least a project file...

Comment: You can also use CMake for that...

Comment: @Nyerguds hehe, well it all depends what OP wants.  Back in the old days this was completely legitimate.  Not even a makefile!

Comment: @MickyD Well the "if you want barebones, don't use an IDE" argument is definitely a valid one.

Comment: I Dont think the New Folder Method works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because _[your question is just a rant in disguise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_

Comment: @Nyerguds OP has made it clear he doesnt want **any files**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you create a new Project in Visual Studio you are using `Templates`.

[image: Screenshot of the 'New Project Dialog from Visual Studio']

2. If you want the 'rocky' from scratch process just select the `Empty Project`.

**But I won't recommend this!**

The purpose of this given templates is to avoid errors, common mistakes and preventing of repeating your self. Also to setup the right hooks for debugging in the Visual Studio IDE.

*Especially `Universal Apps` need a lot of configuration. So why trying doing all by yourself and spend a lot of hours of reading and trying if you can have the whole process in second?*

Comment: Thank you this is wat i ment. Althou it seems kind of obvious now. Do you think this question is redundent? should i remove it?

Comment: @ChrisFraser The mind is a curious thing, could imaged somebody else have the same question if he starts using VS.